# Trying to install Pardiso in Julia on Windows

Tags: julia

I am trying to install Pardiso 6 (non-mkl) version on Windows. (https://github.com/JuliaSparse/Pardiso.jl)

I have followed the instructions and have created the environment variable to point to the Pardiso libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll file. However, I am getting an error.

The output of: `Pkg.build("Pardiso")` is:

> could not load library
>   "C:/Users/XXX/Documents/JuliaPardiso/libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll" The
>   specified module could not be found. Pardiso library
>   =============== Looking for libraries with name: libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll, libpardiso500-WIN-X86-64.dll. Looking in
>   "C:\Users\XXX.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.2.0-1\packages\Pardiso\swIFG\deps"
>   for libraries Looking in "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\JuliaPardiso\" for
>   libraries
>       found "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\JuliaPardiso\libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll",
>   attempting to load it...
>       failed to load due to: did not find libpardiso, assuming PARDISO 5/6 is not installed MKL Pardiso
>   ============= did not find MKLROOT environment variable, assuming MKL is not installed WARNING: no Pardiso library managed to load

Comment: Looks like you skipped this part of the directions: "Set the MKLROOT environment variable. See the MKL getting started manual for a thorough guide how to set this variable correctly, typically done by executing something like source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64."

Comment: I am not trying to install the MKL version of Pardiso and am trying to install the Pardiso project version which should only need the environment variable that points to the Pardiso Project dll file.

Comment: What happens if you directly `Libdl.dlopen()` that DLL path?  It looks like Julia tries to `dlopen()` it, but fails.  If you manually run it, you may see a more detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @staticfloat I have done what you suggested, this is the resulting output: `Libdl.dlopen("C:/Users/XXX/Documents/JuliaPardiso/libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll", Libdl.RTLD_GLOBAL)`

ERROR: could not load library "C:/Users/XX/Documents/JuliaPardiso/libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll"
The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Here is the stacktrace @staticfloat, I hope this somehow helps!


Stacktrace:
 [1] #dlopen#3(::Bool, ::typeof(dlopen), ::String, ::UInt32) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Libdl\src\Libdl.jl:109
 [2] dlopen(::String, ::UInt32) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Libdl\src\Libdl.jl:109
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1

Comment: Does that .dll file being passed into `dlopen` actually exist?

Comment: Yes it does @staticfloat, here is a pwd() and readdir() I just performed:

julia> `pwd()`
"C:\\Users\\XXX\\Documents\\JuliaPardiso"

julia> `readdir()`
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "libpardiso600-WIN-X86-64.dll"

Comment: @LL18 instead of commenting back and forth on SO (which will be very slow), feel free to join the Julia community slack, and direct message me `@staticfloat` and I will try to help you debug this.